# Configuring project browser

Tags: netbeans-8

Is it possible to set 'Recent Projects' panel to open with external window? Currently it opens in tab with latest project so all I can do is just remove it.

I'm using Netbeans 8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the **Recent Projects** list shown on the **My NetBeans** tab of the **Start Page** then you cannot open it with an "external window" since it is just data on a **Start Page** tab.

However, you can float the entire **Start Page**, making that an "external window". To do that:

- Right click the **Start Page** tab which contains the list of recent projects.
- From the drop down menu select **Float**. Alternatively, position the mouse cursor over the **Start Page** tab, hold down the right mouse key and drag the page to its desired location on the screen.

Notes:

- The floating is persistent across restarts of NetBeans.
- To restore a floating window to its previous location just right-click its tab and select **Dock** from the drop down menu.
- This works for any window with a tab in NetBeans.

[image]

Comment: Are there any options to start NetBeans **without** opening latest project?